# Is there a java class or fuction to do a 1-D Convolution of samples arrays?

Tags: android, audio, convolution

I have found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291524/how-to-optimize-convolution-matrix-in-android) a Matrix convolution image orientated and is multi dimensional, i a have'nt found a 1D convolution, tried to make my own but it's too slow

Answer (score 3):

To calculate the convolution of 1-D arrays in JAVA take a look at [Commons-math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/math3/util/MathArrays.html#convolve(double[],%20double[]))